# How can I use 3-dimensional data as a class property?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization, multidimensional-array

It's been a long time since I worked with C++, but I have a class that uses 3-dimensional data and I can't figure out how I can make this work. I need the sizes of the dimensions to be defined in the constructor. I tried this in the header:

```
class CImage
{
public:
    float values[][][];
...
}
```

and this in the constructor:

```
CImage::CImage(int cols, int rows, int depth)
{
    values[cols][rows][depth];
}
```

but this returns the error: "declaration of `values' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first".

Also using this in the constructor does not work:

```
values = new float[cols][rows][depth];
```

I also tried using vector, but without much success. Header:

```
vector<vector<vector<float> > > values;
```

Nothing in constructor. No compiler errors, but when I try to set a value:

```
values[c][r][d] = value;
```

the program crashes.

It seems so basic, but I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program crashes when accessing that vector because it is empty, i.e. there are no elements at those indexes.

The best way to go about this is to make a linear, one-dimensional, vector (or even an array), and access it with a pair of operator()'s, see [C++FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.11) for details. Or use [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class CImage
{
        int X, Y, Z;
        std::vector<float> values;
public:
        CImage(int cols, int rows, int depth)
                : X(cols), Y(rows), Z(depth),
                values(cols*rows*depth) {}
        float operator()(int x, int y, int z) const
        {
                return values[Z*Y*x + Z*y + z];
                // or you lay it out differently in memory
                // if you please, transparent to the user:
                // return values[x + X*y + X*Y*z];
        }
        float& operator()(int x, int y, int z)
        {
                return values[Z*Y*x + Z*y + z];
                // likewise, in a different layout
                // return values[x + X*y + X*Y*z];
        }
};

int main()
{
        CImage ci(3,3,3);
        ci(2,2,2) = 7.0;
        std::cout << ci(2,2,2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: if you use `operator[]` it looks even better

Comment: @swegi: Yes, I was sanity-checking myself.

Comment: In the constructor, at the line where it says values(rows*cols*depth); my compiler gives me this error: no match for call to `(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >) (int)'. Does this have something to do with the way I write my constructor? Your notation gets lots of red underlining from my IDE.

Comment: @RemiX: tested with MSVC 2010 on Windows, gcc 4.4.4 on Linux, Sun C++ 5.8 on Solaris. What IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: Using Netbeans 6.8, with MinGW32 compiler. I tried creating a local vector<float> v1 in the constructor and it would accept the (rows*cols*depth) parameter, but the values property defined in the header won't.

Comment: @RemiX: Oh, I see, you must have written `values(rows*cols*depth);` on a line of its own. That's a syntax error, yes. Members should be initalized before the opening brace of the constructor, but if you want to do that within the constructor body, write `values.resize(rows*cols*depth);`

Comment: Ah, seems that I made a mistake with a for-loop that made the index go out of bounds. The line values = vector<float>(rows*cols*depth); works, just like the line values.resize(rows*cols*depth); Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just to poiny out why Cubbi is right, this would be the constructor of the 3d-vector:

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>> values;
// create vector [dim0][dim1][dim2]
// init value: init
size_t dim0 = 3;
size_t dim1 = 3;
size_t dim2 = 3;
float init = 0.42f;
values = vector<vector<vector<float>>>
         (
            dim0,
            vector<vector<float>>
            (
                dim1,
                vector<float>
                (
                    dim0,
                    init
                )
            )
         );
```

Nice, isn't it?

Besides, you cannot declare a `float values[][][];` because arrays reside on the stack, so the compiler has to know at compile time what size that array has (exception to this: C99 variable length arrays, but this would'nt be C++). You could declare a `float*** values;` (using `new float[c][r][d];` in the ctor), but this is awful, too.